# What is the subject of "to find" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure, subjects

I can't figure out the subject of "**to find**" in this [sentence from a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZIgn5l73hmEC&pg=PA147&dq=Each%20habit%20demands%20appropriate%20conditions%20for%20its%20exercise%20and%20when%20habits%20are%20numerous%20and%20complex,%20as%20with%20the%20human%20organism,%20to%20find%20these%20conditions%20involves%20search%20and%20experimentation.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVs_iXs4rfAhVlvFkKHTXwA-QQ6AEIKjAA). It appears to me it should connect with **Each habit demands appropriate conditions**, making **appropriate conditions** its subject. But I recall that *demand someone to do* is wrong, as has been discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234706/i-demand-they-do-i-demand-them-to).

> Each habit demands appropriate conditions for its exercise and when habits are numerous and complex, as with the human organism, **to find** these conditions involves search and experimentation.

I am inclined to say **to find** is short for "in order to find". Is that the case?

Comment: [to find these conditions] {involves} [search and experimentation.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *subject* of the verb *involves* in the following independent clause:

**To find** these conditions involves search and experimentation.

It can also be replaced with 'finding'.

https://www.englishgrammar.org/gerunds-infinitives-subjects/

https://www.englishgrammar.org/infinitive-clause-subject-object/

Comment: Agreed. My answer was going to be: use 'finding' instead.